# How to cover an element with another element by scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

For demonstration look at this website:

http://www.mojo-themes.com/item/esco-one-page-portfolio/demo/

as you can see, when you slowly scroll down the page, the top video is not going up, the lower white area starts covering the video. I did my best to implement this but I failed, any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it `position:fixed` and set its `z-index` to be `-1`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/jB3Fd/

Comment: what if I want it to be in the middle of the page not necessarily at the top ?

Comment: @Drupalist, in my example i have explicitly set it to fill the whole page.. you can change the `top`/`left`/`bottom`/`right` properties to put it wherever you want..

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your foreground node after background video node in DOM.
2. Set `position: fixed` on background video element and `position: relative` on foreground element.

http://jsfiddle.net/97bCv/

Comment: what if I want it to be in the middle of the page not necessarily at the top ?